# How to get value of last node added to the database

Tags: java, android, firebase, onclick, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to access a certain value within the last added Firebase node. In my database I have a set of Clients, which through my app, can be added to. Inside a client there's a piece of information titled 'clientName'. I would like to get this value.

[image]

Once I get the value, I'm trying to give a toast message showing that value.

Here is my code inside the onClick method of my button. I'm not sure why it's not working. If you know of another way I could do this or a way to fix my current code I'd really appreciate it!

**Thanks in advance guys!**

```
my_button[bt].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (my_button[Index].getId() == ((ImageButton) v).getId()) {
                                String bla = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("id");
                                String address = "https://console.firebase.google.com/project/cssecond-92a2d/database/data/clients/" +bla+"/clientName";
                                Firebase ref = new Firebase(address);
                                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                        Toast.makeText(HomePageNews.this,"In your hands you have: "+ value ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: When you start the yout activity what is the value of `String bla`?

Comment: Hi Alex, I think it's the last generate Clients ID. A node that would look like: 'Ki1FB78... etc etc' . Cheers @AlexM.

Comment: Are you sure is not `null`?

Comment: @AlexM. hmm, It may be. How would I adapt it to get the ID node?

Comment: As i see in your code, that id, named by you `bla` it's coming from an `intent` from another activity. Check if you add that id correct to the intent. Use a `Log.d("TAG", bla);` when you start your activity to be sure is not `null`.

Comment: It looks like I've missed out a line of code. So it was Null! Let me just add it in and see if it works. Thanks @AlexM.

Comment: Ok, please keep me posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142294/discussion-between-joe-and-alex-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine in your code. The problem is this line of code:

```
String bla = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("id");
```

The id that is returning from that `intent` is `null`, so your `reference` is also `null`. In order to fix this, you need to change the code to get the correct value from the intent that is coming from your previous activity and than it should work.